# Displaying JSON Data Through fragment?

Tags: android, json, android-fragments

I was Given A Project as : please read it

## SAMPLE JSON --

[ { "slot":"A" , "name":"Dummy Subject 1", "code":"SCD1", "class number":"12345", "total students": "67" }, { "slot":"B", "name":"Dummy Subject 2", "code":"SCD2", "class number":"12346", "total students": "29" }, { "slot":"C", "name":"Dummy Subject 3", "code":"SCD3", "class number":"12347", "total students": "41" }, { "slot":"D", "name":"Dummy Subject 4", "code":"SCD4", "class number":"12348", "total students": "65" }, { "slot":"E", "name":"Dummy Subject 5", "code":"SCD5", "class number":"12349", "total students": "55" } ]

Sample JSON data which has information of 5 Dummy subjects and information related to each subject. Download this JSON data, parse the information out from it and store in Shared Preferences, as per your wish. 
display  in an ExpandableListView with name and code as head. On expanding , show other details of it.

## what i was not able to do  this for N no. of objects ...if there were n no. of objects in JSON data....Please help with this question also ...

## so i did This project as per instructions but now i am given same project and do it in fragment as #list item should be name and code and data should be its data ...

## here's my code via using activity ...please tell how to do same using fragment ..

# json_parse_class.java

```
        package com.office.tracker;
    // Nikhil Verma 13BCE0037 9787029484 L-217
    import java.io.IOException;

    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class json_dpa extends Activity {
        HttpClient client;
        JSONObject dummy1;
        SharedPreferences json_spref;;
        String[] datas = null;
        TextView tv;
        public static String s1="Default^Default^Default^Default^Default^Default^Default^Default^" +
                "Default^Default^Default^Default^Default^Default^Default^Default^" +
                "Default^Default^Default^Default^Default^Default^Default^Default^Default";
        private static final String SLOT = "slot";
        static final String NAME = "name";
        static final String CODE = "code";
        static final String ClASS_NUMBER = "cno.";
        static final String TOTAL_STUDENTS = "ts";
        static final String TOTAL = "t";
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
        public static int ob_counter = 0;
        public String deta[] = null;
        private static final String PREFS_NAME = "json_prefname";
        int count = 0;
        final static String URL = "http://www.gdgvitvellore.com/samplejson/";

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.json);
            client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.json_id);
            json_spref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        //  this.ob_counter = counter;
        String[] index = { "slot", "name", "code", "class number",
                    "total students" };
            new getdata().execute(index);
        }

        public int  async(int counter) 
        {
        this.ob_counter = counter;
        return 0;
        }

        public JSONObject gdg(int r) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException,
                JSONException {
    ob_counter=r;
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(URL);
            HttpResponse rtr = client.execute(get);
            int status = rtr.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity e = rtr.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
                JSONArray detail = new JSONArray(data);
                JSONObject dummy = detail.getJSONObject(ob_counter);
                return dummy;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(json_dpa.this, "Error ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                return null;
            }
        }

        public class getdata extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                try {

                    dummy1 = gdg(0);
                    String mystr1 = dummy1.getString(params[0]);
                    String mystr2 = dummy1.getString(params[1]);
                    String mystr3 = dummy1.getString(params[2]);
                    String mystr4 = dummy1.getString(params[3]);
                    String mystr5 = dummy1.getString(params[4]);
                    dummy1=null;
                    dummy1 = gdg(1);
                    String mystr6 = dummy1.getString(params[0]);
                    String mystr7 = dummy1.getString(params[1]);
                    String mystr8 = dummy1.getString(params[2]);
                    String mystr9 = dummy1.getString(params[3]);
                    String mystr10 = dummy1.getString(params[4]);
                    dummy1=null;
                    dummy1 = gdg(2);
                    String mystr11 = dummy1.getString(params[0]);
                    String mystr12 = dummy1.getString(params[1]);
                    String mystr13 = dummy1.getString(params[2]);
                    String mystr14 = dummy1.getString(params[3]);
                    String mystr15 = dummy1.getString(params[4]);
                    dummy1=null;
                    dummy1 = gdg(3);
                    String mystr16 = dummy1.getString(params[0]);
                    String mystr17 = dummy1.getString(params[1]);
                    String mystr18 = dummy1.getString(params[2]);
                    String mystr19 = dummy1.getString(params[3]);
                    String mystr20 = dummy1.getString(params[4]);
                    dummy1=null;
                    dummy1 = gdg(4);
                    String mystr21 = dummy1.getString(params[0]);
                    String mystr22 = dummy1.getString(params[1]);
                    String mystr23 = dummy1.getString(params[2]);
                    String mystr24 = dummy1.getString(params[3]);
                    String mystr25 = dummy1.getString(params[4]);
                    editor = json_spref.edit();
                    editor.putString(SLOT, mystr1);
                    editor.putString(NAME, mystr2);
                    editor.putString(CODE, mystr3);
                    editor.putString(ClASS_NUMBER, mystr4);
                    editor.putString(TOTAL_STUDENTS, mystr5);
                    editor.putString(TOTAL, mystr1+"^"+mystr2+"^"+mystr3+"^"+mystr4+"^"+mystr5+"^"+mystr6+"^"+mystr7
                            +"^"+mystr8+"^"+mystr9+"^"+mystr10+"^"+mystr11+"^"+mystr12+"^"+mystr13+"^"+mystr14+"^"+mystr15
                            +"^"+mystr16+"^"+mystr17+"^"+mystr18+"^"+mystr19+"^"+mystr20+"^"+mystr21+"^"+mystr22
                            +"^"+mystr23+"^"+mystr24+"^"+mystr25);
                    editor.commit();
                    return mystr1;
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                s1 = json_spref.getString(TOTAL, "defaut Slot");
                tv.setText(s1);

            }

        }

    }
```

list_main class.java

```
          package com.office.tracker;

      import android.app.Activity;
      import android.content.Intent;
      import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.view.Menu;
      import android.view.MenuInflater;
      import android.view.MenuItem;
      import android.view.View;
      import android.view.Window;
      import android.view.WindowManager;
      import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
      import android.widget.Button;
      import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

      public class json_list_main extends Activity implements OnClickListener
      { // Nikhil Verma 13BCE0037 9787029484 L-217
          ExpandableListView elv;
          Button but;

          protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
              getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
              setContentView(R.layout.json_exp_list);
              elv=(ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.json_exp_listID);
              but=(Button) findViewById(R.id.list_button);
              but.setOnClickListener(this);
              //json_dpa ob=new json_dpa();
              //ob.async(0);

              //String s1=ob.json_spref.getString(ob.NAME, "defaut Slot");
              elv.setAdapter(new json_exp_list_view(this));
          }

          public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
              MenuInflater mf = getMenuInflater();
              mf.inflate(R.menu.cool_menu, menu);
              return true;
          }

          @Override
          public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              switch (item.getItemId()) {
              case R.id.aboutus:
                  Intent rob = new Intent("com.office.tracker.ABOUTUS");
                  startActivity(rob);

                  break;
          //    case R.id.preferences:
                  //Intent roby = new Intent("com.office.tracker.PREFS");
                  //startActivity(roby);
                  //break;
              case R.id.exit:
                  finish();
                  break;
              }
              return false;
          }

          public void onClick(View v) {
              if(v.getId()==R.id.list_button){
                  Intent rob = new Intent("com.office.tracker.JSON_DPA");
                  startActivity(rob);

              }

          }

      }




custom adapter class.java




        package com.office.tracker;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;

        public class json_exp_list_view extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
        private Context context;
        int i=0;
        json_dpa ob=new json_dpa();
        String ret=ob.s1;
        String i1="Slot -";
        String i2="Name -";
        String i3="Code -";
        String i4="Class No. -";
        String i5="Total Students -";

        String[] splitArray = ret.split("\\^");//split whenever at least one whitespace is encountered


        //String s1=ob.json_spref.getString(ob.NAME, "defaut Slot");
        //json_dpa ob=new json_dpa();
        //String name1=ob.name_ret();
        //String code1=ob.code_ret();
        String[] parent={i2+splitArray[1]+" , "+i3+splitArray[2],i2+splitArray[6]+" , "+i3+splitArray[7],i2+splitArray[11]+" , "+i3+splitArray[12]
                ,i2+splitArray[16]+" , "+i3+splitArray[17],i2+splitArray[21]+" , "+i3+splitArray[22]};
        String[][] child={{i1+splitArray[0],i4+splitArray[3],splitArray[4]},
                {i1+splitArray[5],i4+splitArray[8],i5+splitArray[9]}
        ,{i1+splitArray[10],i4+splitArray[13],i5+splitArray[14]},
        {i1+splitArray[15],i4+splitArray[18],i5+splitArray[19]},
        {i1+splitArray[20],i4+splitArray[23],i5+splitArray[24]}};
        public json_exp_list_view(Context context) {
            this.context=context;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int arg0, int arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int arg0, int arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int GroupPosition, int ChildPosition, boolean arg2, View arg3,
                ViewGroup arg4) {
            TextView tv=new TextView(context);
            tv.setText(child[GroupPosition][ChildPosition]);
            tv.setPadding(90, 15, 15, 15);
            tv.setTextSize(25);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            return tv;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int GroupPosition) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return child[GroupPosition].length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int GroupPosition) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return GroupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return parent.length;
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int GroupPosition) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return GroupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int GroupPosition, boolean arg1, View arg2, ViewGroup arg3) {

            TextView tv=new TextView(context);
            tv.setText(parent[GroupPosition]);
            tv.setPadding(110, 15, 15, 15);
            tv.setTextSize(27);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            return tv;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: just copy&paste 'til N ... do you know loops?

Comment: woah...assignment alert...you won't learn a thing if you hand out your assignments

Comment: i tried that in post execute but it crashed every time!! and see i have used 25 string variables for this...whenever i used string array it crashed ..

Comment: Hey Selvin please tell me how to change my code so that i can  run it  for n no. of json objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To covert your JSON string to an object you need to do the following:

Go to the following link and download GSON:
https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/detail?name=google-gson-1.5-release.zip&can=4&q=

Copy it in the your project

Create class that represents List of subjects

Than where you need to convert JSON to list of subjects do the following in code:

```
//import the packeges

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.tekpub.models.Production;

//type of objct we need to convert JSON string to
Type typeOfDest = new TypeToken<List<Subjects>>(){}.getType();

Gson gson = new Gson(); 
//return the object     
return gson.fromJson(input, typeOfDest);
```

Comment: Hey thats not what i meant ... i have a link that has the data in  JSON Object format(i have just copied the Json Data to show)....i mainly want to ask how to  change my code so that it runs for n no.s of json formatted objects ... and do the same via Fragment.

Comment: your question doesn't mention all this. pls create another question and put the details propoerly. i have tried to provide you answer based on the question.

Comment: please see in this ... if u can help

Comment: This is for n no of JSON objects. all json objects will be serialized to an object i.e. is list of subjects. Do you want to know how to do it from the link? in that case you need to use HttpCLient to read the string from the uri and than use the above code to serialize it to list

Comment: Please can u read through  my question and see my  code once ... i have done that already....i have parsed the data using Json and then in my AsyncTask method > DoInBackground i had to create 25 string variables for getting data and then saving it in shared pref.. and then in post execute i have taken that data in string variable and then used that in other ExpandablelistView  type Class and splitted that data and stores that in string array and then displayed accordingly .

Comment: what i want to do is to somehow do it for n no. of objects without having to create this many strings..

Comment: And then what i have to do is to  the same via Fragment i.e. list view denotes object name+code and then its new fragment gives its other details.

Comment: instead of creating n string variables you should create a List<String> variable and than serialize all the json objects into that single list object. which you can do using the code given above

Comment: also how to use fragment in activity check your other question i have provided an answer there

Comment: ...Can you please show some code of how to do that... i know less lists...please can you show me some code... about getting n json objects in my code

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), a library to easily parse JSON data to/for object. You can even parameters it